# angularjs, $compiled templates and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

Essentially, I take two templates inside a compile function of a directive.
I compile them once and for all (via $compile) in the compile phase of the directive.
In the link phase of the directive, I watch a scope variable and applies one or the other compiled template to the scope.

```
testApp.directive('testField', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var viewFn = $compile("<div>View: <span ng-repeat='x in [1,2,3]'>{{x}}</span></div>");
      var editFn = $compile("<div>Edit: <span ng-repeat='x in [4,5,6]'>{{x}}</span></div>");

      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var innerScope = null;

        scope.$watch("mode", function (mode) {
          if (innerScope) innerScope.$destroy();
          innerScope = scope.$new();

          if (mode == 'VIEW') {
              element.empty().append(viewFn(innerScope));
          } else {
              element.empty().append(editFn(innerScope));
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

It works fine, except when the template includes a Ng-repeat that is not the root element in which case it behave strangely:

To reproduce, go to http://plnkr.co/edit/RCqlNWTVdXVoMQCkFcQn?p=preview
And switch a couple of time from Edit to View.

You'll notice the number of iterations of ng-repeat grows over time.
First time, it displays 123 and 456, like it should

After the first back and forth between view and edit, it displays 123123 and 456456

And it keeps adding one iteration every time you do a back and forth between view and edit.

Comment: Note that if instead of $compiling the template once and linking it as needed, I compile it every time, it works fine. But it seems to defeat the purpose of the separation of compile and link.

`element.html("<div>Edit: <span ng-repeat='x in [4,5,6]'>{{x}}</span></div>");
$compile(element.contents())(innerScope)`

Answer (score 1):

I probably found the solution shortly after posting.

The problem apparently lies in the fact that ng-repeat needs to clone the template.

After stumbling on a comment in the angular source, turns out we can pass a second argument to the function returned by compile.

This second argument is a function that is called with a clone of the template (and the scope being linked to).

so instead of

```
      if (mode == 'VIEW') {
          element.empty().append(viewFn(innerScope));
      } else {
          element.empty().append(editFn(innerScope));
      }
```

I can do

```
      function setElts(elts) {
         element.empty().append(elts);
      }

      if (mode == 'VIEW') {
        viewFn(innerScope, setElts);
      } else {
        editFn(innerScope, setElts);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLAeAVllEgfZmLNfrpq8?p=preview).

Firstly, you inject new dom directly in your view. After, catch it and apply $compile.

like this;

```
var viewFn = "<div>View: <span ng-repeat='x in [1,2,3]'>{{x}}</span></div>";
...
element.html(viewFn);
...
$compile(tElement.contents())(innerScope);
```