# Use combination of compile in directive and ng-repeat in view prevent updating scope elements list correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAC5uXx2GPaGO1VoU75w?p=preview) (link updated), I'm sorry but I was not able to make it work again as it works in my project but it helps for reading purpose instead of pasting here my code.

```
$scope.elements = [
{
  'value': 'Default text', 
  'elem_type_name': 'text field'
}, {
  'value': 'example@email.com', 
  'elem_type_name': 'email field'
}];
```

In fact initially my code works and I'm well able to render the right view, nevertheless in my code I have a submit button at the bottom of my page.

When clicking on it, it generates a new API call to update my current scope variable (elements list).

Some of those could be remain after the API call, some could be removed and some new could be added.

Unfortunately when I click on this submit button the scope is weirdly not well analysed, so if the same element remains with the same id, it is duplicated. If I get a completely new list of elements, I will see the previous elements + the new ones.

It seems that I have the same problem as this one: [Another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957525/angularjs-compiled-templates-and-ng-repeat/) but in my case after each click on the button I need to empty completely the elements scope variable before each API call.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Your Plunkr example is just a Hello World app

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sorry I updated my plunker link, I didn't save

Answer (score 0):

In your call, you could set `$scope.elements = ''`, and then you could assign `$scope.elements = response.data`, or whatever you are defining the results as. For example:

```
$http.get('jsonFile.json')
    .then(function(jsonData) {
        $scope.elements = '';
        $scope.elements = jsonData.data;
    });
```

This will clean $scope.elements, and then update with only the new response data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I didn't post everything because I did a mistake when editing my plunker, please have a look on it in my edited question.

Comment: @VincentDiMaria your Plunkr is empty for me. Make sure you click 'save' and make sure it is set to public and not private

Comment: Indeed I pasted too quickly the link, sorry about that, the link is now finally the right one.